# DbContext.EnsureCreated() : ArgumentNullException only on RELEASE build

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, entity-framework-core

I am using microsoft `ef-core` and `Sqlite` database in my `xamarin-forms` app.  My model is quite big, so I guess it's not a good idea to drop it here. I was working on the app for couple weeks and tested on my phone in **Debug** mode - everything worked perfectly.

But as soon as I've built **RELEASE** version - I got ArgumentNullException right on `DbContext.EnsureCreated()` call. I could find it using console output. So it says:

```
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key
```

On **DEBUG** build my application works perfectly fine, and I have no build-dependent precompiler directives in my code also. Using Visual Studio 2017

Any thoughts or advices on what can I check?

UPD: here is stacktrace I got in Release:

```
I/mono-stdout(24851): TRACE:  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].TryInsert (TKey key, TValue value, System.Collections.Generic.InsertionBehavior behavior) [0x00008] in <d029cac6f9824b0bb72d5eb6d48d11f3>:0
I/mono-stdout(24851):   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].Add (TKey key, TValue value) [0x00000] in <d029cac6f9824b0bb72d5eb6d48d11f3>:0
I/mono-stdout(24851):   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Query.Internal.SqliteDateTimeAddTranslator..ctor (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ISqlExpressionFactory sqlExpressionFactory) [0x000c5] in <7b7aa88a95d54aa786bada86edd4821a>:0
I/mono-stdout(24851):   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Query.Internal.SqliteMethodCallTranslatorProvider..ctor (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalMethodCallTranslatorProviderDependencies dependencies) [0x0001d] in <7b7aa88a95d54aa786bada86edd4821a>:0
I/mono-stdout(24851):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
I/mono-stdout(24851):   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters, System.Boolean wrapExceptions) [0x00005] in <d029cac6f9824b0bb72d5eb6d48d11f3>:0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind this is that the linker is being overly aggressive and it strips *System.DateTime* class from *mscorlib* assembly. The proper fix is, instead of *preserveDateTimeMethods* solution that you mentioned, to create a [Custom Linker Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/linker).

1. Create an empty file **LinkDescription.xml**
2. Add it to the OS-level project (Android, iOS, etc).
3. Set its build action to **LinkDescription**
4. Add **System.DateTime** to the linker block

Here's how:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<linker>
  <assembly fullname="mscorlib">
    <type fullname="System.DateTime" preserve="methods" />
  </assembly>
</linker>
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked to me and I guess this is really the right way of doing it. Thanks for sharing link with more info about linking also.

Answer (score 1):

So, I've searched for hours and as soon as I've posted quiestion..

Looks like it's a `ef-core` bug - a linker problem working with DateTime types leading to attempt of adding null-key value to Dictionary. 
Links to bug discussion:

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/14091

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10963

I had this problem on my Android release build, so I've added line of code from one of comments on first discussion.

Added this line in my `MainActivity.cs` before Xamarin.Forms initialization:

```
 var preserveDateTimeMethods = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(1).AddHours(1).AddMinutes(1).AddSeconds(1);
```

It resolved my problem. Hope it helps somebody.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please do not forget to mark your answer after two days, it will help others who have similar issue.